# how to build a bot for on-line flash game?

Tags: flash, browser, mouse, bots

there are a lot of flash games that ask u to do repetitive actions. an example would be FarmVille or getting statistics on on-line poker game.

What is the best way to create an interface between what you see on the screen, a bot's algorithm and clicking of the mouse.

so basically, when i'm playing a texas hold'em on face book and if i get AA i want the bot to click all-in. if i don't get AA i want to fold. this is just an example, not the actual strategy. or another examples would be routing tasks in farmville.

so basically. it has to grab a picture of the screen. recognize patterns and convert them into an input of the algorithm. the output algorithms would be clicking on some other (may be same) patterns.

any suggestions?

Comment: there is a similar post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964529/online-trading-bot which has a link to building a poker bot http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot. obviously i'd like to do smtn similar but i'm curious if there are better tools these days. And even though it's easier to look at the data sent and recieved, looking at the screen and then making the computer move the mouse is more general.

Comment: looks like this might be also one way to do it http://www.mjtnet.com/blog/2006/10/11/see-the-screen-with-image-recognition/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have experience building a simple computer vision based bot for a online card game.

I used a crossplatform python library called **autopy** to handle automated mouse click and keyboard input. The bot capture screen every 0.5 sec, then convert the captured screen into a numpy array for analysis. Python has good image processing (PIL, OpenCV python binding) and machine learning utilities (scikit-learn). For simple image pattern recognition, the bot extract mean of pixel brightness over a image region to make decision. For complicated ones, OpenCV template matching and SVM classifier are being used.

The server caught my bot the first time, so I guess some there's bot detection on the server side. After I added more randomness and flexible decision making, the bot has bypassed serverside bot detection.

All took me a Saturday and I enjoyed Sunday.

Answer (score 4):

Before attempting to parse screen images and produce mouse clicks (which would be exceedingly difficult), first take a look at the data actually being sent/received by the game between the browser and the server.  Interact with the game as normal and use something like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the packets and see if it's something you can automate.

It's unlikely (since they specifically *don't* want people to do what you're trying to do), but it's possible that the communication with the server is just simple requests with parameters.  (I know this was the case a long time ago with MySpace games, such as Dragon Wars and Mafia Wars.)

If the data is something you can parse and understand then you can skip the Flash interface entirely and just write your own.

Comment: wireshark sounds good. i will look into that. but i'm also curious to c if i can just interact through screen since it's more general and might also save time trying to figure out values that were sent.

Comment: @kirill_igum: There are probably libraries out there for sending data to a screen in the form of mouse/keyboard input.  For example, WatiN is a decent .NET library for interacting with a browser (HTML elements, not so much for Flash, though there may be others).  However, reading data from the screen is going to be extremely difficult.  Even if it's possible (feasible may be a more accurate word) I don't think it's going to be as generic as you expect.

Comment: I don't follow how it can be difficult if you know what you are looking for. For example: I lunch a program that takes a screen shot of the flash game or the browser or the screen. convert it to a matrix where each elements is a number that represents a color. a code will match a sub-matrix to one from my library (pre-stored patterns that i'm looking for). if it matches, the code outputs the location(s) of the patterns.   so when i want to use it i would just have to input the patterns that i'm looking for. and if they change. i would have to change them by hand

Comment: I will still look into WatiN. I do agree with you that going through data directly would be simpler in a lot of cases but I would like to explore or have knowledge about both of the approaches.

Comment: @kirill_igum: It does sound it would be a pretty sweet open source library.  You can probably find some decent community interest in a project like this, but I'm no expert on hosting an open source project.

Comment: I built a bot using Awesomium to host the webpage in my .Net app and to click elements, and a local http proxy (also embedded in the app) to read values instead of recognizing them from screen

Answer (score 1):

I've made many bot using c# and a simple webBrowser control. 
Usually however i try to automate the "click" function on a element without the use of actually simulating a cursor and invoking a click.

**Example:**

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementid").InvokeMember("Click");
```

I find this much easier than actually simulating a cursor, however simulating a cursor can also achieved relatively easily , here's the code i usually make use of:

```
//Example of how to use it:
    Point controlLoc = this.PointToScreen(webbrowser1.Location);
    controlLoc.X = controlLoc.X + webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementid").OffsetRectangle.Left;
    controlLoc.Y = controlLoc.Y + webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementid").OffsetRectangle.Top;
    Cursor.Position = controlLoc;
    MouseSimulator.ClickLeftMouseButton();

public class MouseSimulator
 {
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct INPUT
{
    public SendInputEventType type;
    public MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion mkhi;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MouseInputData mi;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    public ushort wVk;
    public ushort wScan;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
    public int uMsg;
    public short wParamL;
    public short wParamH;
}
struct MouseInputData
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public uint mouseData;
    public MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
[Flags]
enum MouseEventFlags : uint
{
    MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,
    MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
    MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,
    MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
    MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
    MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
    MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
    MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,
    MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,
    MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
    MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
    MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
}
enum SendInputEventType : int
{
    InputMouse,
    InputKeyboard,
    InputHardware
}

public static void ClickLeftMouseButton()
{

    INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
    mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
    mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

    INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
    mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
    mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
}
```

This will Left click on any element named "elementid" in a loaded webBrowser control. Notice the other MouseEventFlags that can easily be implemented:

Here's a example for right click:

```
public static void ClickRightMouseButton()
{
    INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
    mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
    mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
    SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

    INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
    mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
    mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
    SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
}
```